# When do CA-25's special election results come out?

Tags: united-states, voting, california

I saw that there is a special election for California's 25th district. It is considered a toss-up, though I feel that the Democrat has an advantage because an even Cook PVI means that it leans Democratic by 2 to 4 points because the average of the 2012 and 2016 elections was D+3. Anyway, when are the results for the special election likely to be released? I'm getting anxious.

The Washington Post article is at https://www.washingtonpost.com/elections/election-results/california-special-election-live-results/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polls in California close at 8pm PDT.

Normally, results start to come in a short time after that.  It is unclear whether the coronavirus pandemic will lead to delays in counting, but I would be surprised if no precincts have reported by midnight.

Answer (score 1):

[California’s 25th District Is Up for Grabs in an Unusual Special Election](https://www.nbclosangeles.com/news/politics/decision-2020/california-us-house-25th-district-election-katie-hill-mike-garcia-christy-smith-vote/2361190/)

> The results are unlikely to be known for at least for several days, due in part to California's unusual vote-counting rules.

[**The Official Canvass of the Vote**](https://www.sos.ca.gov/elections/official-canvass/)

> The California Elections Code requires that the official canvass begin no later than the Thursday following the election, that it be open to the public, and that it continue daily (Saturdays, Sundays, and holidays excepted) for not less than six hours each day until completed. The county elections officials must complete the official canvass no later than the 30th day after the election and submit a certified statement of the results of the election to the Secretary of State by the 31st day.

Comment: Not sure, the one above is more standard

Comment: @NumberFile - In answer to your deleted question, ["An unknown number of ballots remained uncounted and Los Angeles County, where most of them are located, was not expected to update its tally until Friday."](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/wireStory/republicans-cusp-retaking-california-us-house-seat-70652520).